# MK3 Ford Focus Jack Points

Tags: focus, jack

I have a brand new MK3 Ford Focus (it's an ST, but I don't think that matters).  I know it has the four jack points in the corners inside the wheels (underneath door sills) but I don't know/can't find where the other jack points are.  I assume that there are spots on the front/rear subframes to jack the car up, but I'm not experienced enough to pick them out from the bottom of the car.

Anyone have an MK3 Focus and know where the jack points are?

Answer (score 1):

[Focushacks.com has this excellent diagram:](http://www.focushacks.com/mod/Jacking:_Raising_and_supporting_your_Focus)

[image]

Comment: This looks like it's for an MK1 focus (1999-2007 in the US). I've seen this diagram while hunting for its MK3 counterpart.  It can't be too different, though.